# Varnish does not serve cached content

Tags: 7, proxies

I have successfully installed Varnish cache with my Drupal instance for both PROD and TEST servers. My PROD server seems to work without any problems. However my TEST server (which has the SAME configurations with the PROD server) does not seems to work. More specifically, i have the same configuration for both Apache and Varnish default.vcl file. My TEST server varnishstat shows that cache_hits are <= with the cache_miss while my PROD server's cache_hits are obviously much higher that cache_miss. I'm desperate with this issue. Don't know what else should i search for.

Comment: You'll need to share more details about your specific configuration, and ideally a small sample of headers and requests to show what is happening on each environment